# Simplier adding of many enum values to a combobox

Tags: c#, function, combobox, enums

I'm very new to c# and Programming and I was wondering how can I put this code into a function.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbInteger);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbBigInt);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbBinary);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbBoolean);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbByte);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbChar);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbCurrency);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbDate);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbDecimal);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbDouble);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbFloat);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbGUID);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbLong);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbLongBinary);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbMemo);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbNumeric);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbSingle);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbText);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbTime);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbTimeStamp);
comboBox1.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbVarBinary);
```

I have 5 ComboBoxes and I thought instead of writing all this for each ComboBox I can make a function but can't figure how to do it. As well is there a way to change the names ? For Example when I drop down the box it shows : dbInteger,dbBigInt ? Can I change those to show Integer, Big Integer ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is your enum defined? Do you want to cover *every* value in the enum?

Answer (score 9):

You could do this in one line

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(DAO.DataTypeEnum)));
```

With regards to the display names, I generally make use of the `DescriptionAttribute` and write a small extension method of extracting that info e.g.

```
public enum DataTypeEnum
{
    [Description("Integer")]
    dbInteger,
    [Description("Big Int")]
    dbBigInt,
    ...
}
```

Then using the following extension method

```
public static class EnumExt
{
    public static string Description(this Enum value)
    {
        var attr = (DescriptionAttribute)value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return attr != null ? attr.Description : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And a little sprinkle of LINQ

```
var enums = (DataType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataType));
combo.Items.AddRange(enums.Select(x => x.Description()).ToArray());
```

Then you should end up with

```
Integer
Big Int
...
```

Comment: Works as a charm (: Thank you very much. Now Is there a way to change the name of the Items?

Comment: Oh yes, I just saw it . But I get an Error on the Extension method :

var attrs = (DescriptionAttribute)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

Saying : Cannot convert type 'object[]' to System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute'

Comment: Hmmm now I get attr.Description - Object does not contain a defenition for "Description" and no extension method 'Description' accepting a first argument of type 'object' :( I guess I'lll just leave it without changing the names

Comment: And now for the LINQ i get : 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'object[]'


and : Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Still getting some errors :( : Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments


Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TResult[]' to 'object[]'

Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Description' and no extension method 'Description' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Sorry for all the trouble...

Comment: I am using GetValues ..I get 3 errors again . : Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments    Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TResult[]' to 'object[]'   and Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I just fired up a machine rather than having constant back/fourths on this. See latest update, all issues should be resolved. Once you confirm could you remove all the comments as to not clog the thread?

Answer (score 2):

```
public void UpdateComboBox(ComboBox cmbBox, Type t)
{
   foreach(string item in Enum.GetNames(t))
   {
       cmbBox.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
UpdateComboBox(comboBox1, typeof(DAO.DataTypeEnum));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that receives the combo box as a parameter:

```
static void PopulateComboBox(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbInteger);
    comboBox.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbBigInt);
    ....
}
```

Call it like this:

```
PopulateComboBox(comboBox1);
PopulateComboBox(comboBox2);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

if you try to enumerate the DAO.DataTypeEnum?:

```
public static void FillComboBox(ComboBox cb)
{
    cb.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(DAO.DataTypeEnum);
}
```

Comment: You should really just use `AddRange` here, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code into a method that accepts a `ComboBox` as a parameter.

```
private void AddValues(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    comboBox.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbInteger);
    comboBox.Items.Add(DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbBigInt);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Then call it using `AddValues(comboBox1);`

---

You can set a display value for the ComboBox too, which you can set to a particular property of the class your binding. I'm not sure you could do that with a list of enumeration values, but if they each have an associated description, you might be able to display that value instead.